# How do I make my UIView retractable when I add it as a subview to a scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, object, calendar

I am making a calendar style app only showing individual days, so I have a scroll view right now for each day starting at midnight and ending at midnight, and I want to be able to tap and create "events" on each day.

So far, I have been able to create UIViews every time I tap on the screen, but now I am trying to edit them when I click on them.

Here is some code in my ViewDidLoad for creating an event:

```
 let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self
```

And here is the code I have in my tapped func:

```
@objc func tapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: scrollView)
    let eventLength = 100
    let eventLocation = CGPoint(x: tapLocation.x, y: tapLocation.y-CGFloat(eventLength/2))
    
    //Creates Rectangle event
    let eventRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: Int(eventLocation.y), width: Int(view.frame.size.width), height: (eventLength))
    let testEventView = UIView(frame: eventRect)
    testEventView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.5667, saturation: 0.58, brightness: 0.89, alpha: 1.0)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(testEventView)
    
}
```

But now, how can I recognize when I tap on each event, and change them depending on which one I tapped on. Like I was thinking about adding a text box on the UIView and editing it when you tap on the text box, but I'm not sure how to make it so the app knows when I tap on each event vs. the whole scrollView.

Sorry for the long and kind of open ended question, but if anyone could point me in the right direction of what to look up, or maybe not using a UIView, or anything that could help me accomplish this event creation would be helpful!  Thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure this will happen naturally. Did you try building it out to see? `UITextView` will automatically respond to tap, so don't need to add another gesture recognizer for that. A tap there should be ignored by `UIScrollView` if it is a subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can add tap gesture to every event view

```
testEventView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                          action: #selector(eventViewTapped(gestureRecognizer:))))

self.scrollView.addSubview(testEventView)
```

---

Then, inside action, you can retrive event view

```
@objc func eventViewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let eventView = gestureRecognizer.view
```

After you have to determine which event view it is.
There are many ways to do it, for example

1. Store eventViews as array, then find corresponding index of selected view from this array
2. Set tag to eventView inside your `tapped` function, retrive tag inside `eventViewTapped`
3. Use some custom ui & data model, that holds all info about event views, just like uitableview does

Comment: @KylanO'Connor nice to hear it! Please mark my question as correct if it fixed you issue.